# iCal: How to display full event title?

Tags: ical

I am new to Mac, Mac OS X and iCal.

In the monthly view of iCal, I found it very inconvenient to read only the first 10-12 characters of an event's title. To read the full length title, I have to do one of the following:

- go to full screen
- reduce font size to "unreadable"
- open the event edit dialog
- go to the daily view

None of the above options satisfies me.

Is there a way to have iCal display additional info (full title, comments...) when mouse stay over an event for one second or so?

Alternatively, is there a way to make a long (> 10 chars) title wrap to a new line rather than being cut with `...`?

Comment: The short answer is no, you've listed the only possible ways

Comment: There are many threads (on other forums) asking about the title wrapping, but I'm afraid it isn't possible. For reference, I found [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3222275?start=0&tstart=0), [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=555762), and [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1908481?start=0&tstart=0).

Comment: @gtm: Would you post this as an answer?

Comment: There is one more option: "Edit" → "Show Inspector"  - or alt+cmd+I - then clicking an event will display the details in the "Inspector" window

Comment: That's not really what I was looking for but this is a convenient feature though.

Comment: @wap26 I did, glad it helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many threads (on other forums) asking about the title wrapping, but I'm afraid it isn't possible. For reference, I found [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3222275?start=0&tstart=0), [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=555762), and [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1908481?start=0&tstart=0).

Answer (score -1):

What MACOSX Version are you using? Because in Lion 10.7.4 using iCal on Monthly view, you just need to click the event and it will pop up all event description.

Comment: Sure, this is what I listed as "open the edit dialog", but then you have to click once again to close the description. I was actually looking for something with no click at all, instead of 2 clicks. I received a brand new MacBook Air just one week ago, so I assume I use the very latest version of Lion.

Comment: You can also press Space to show/hide the info.